# Difference between "nil" ,"empty" and "few space bar typed" in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, null

I have a text box, what values will it contain if:

1. I type nothing.
2. I type few space bars.

Are these 2 different things? Is `nil` different from both of them?

Comment: One simple test could answer your question: `print(text?.isEmpty)`. Possible answers = nil, true and false.

Comment: @MartinR & Eendje ,i tried it but i wanted to know the theory behind this....

Answer (score 2):

`nil` used when an object or value doesn't exist.  `text` on a `UITextField` should never be `nil` as its [default value is the empty string](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/text) (`""`).

The empty string `""` is different from a string with spaces `"   "`.  A string with spaces contains characters, and will have a length however many whitespace characters there are in the string.  The length of the empty string is 0.

Comment: In your first sentence I would replace the word _object_ with _value_ since in Swift `nil` is possible for both `Reference Types` and `Value Types`.

Answer (score 1):

This question must have been asked a lot of times, but a reminder is always welcome for newcomers in iOS development (even if, as marked is the comments, a little experience by yourself could have been useful).

First what is `nil` ? Well, it's nothing, is that simple.  An empty `String` is different from nil, since it's an object, a `String` with 0 characters in it. A `String` with multiple spaces in it is also different from these two values, because the `String` length is different from 0, even if once displayed, your String looks empty !

---

FYI, before iOS6, the default value of the `text` property on an `UITextField` was `nil`, and it was necessary to test it before using it. Now the default value is an empty string  `""`. I guess the `text`is an optional `String` in Swift because of this historical default value.